# Cocoa App Won't Launch on 32-bit Intel?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, 32bit-64bit

My Cocoa application, built in Xcode 3.2, runs perfectly on 64-bit machines but does not launch on a 32-bit Intel Mac. The Architecture is set to Standard(32/64-bit), Valid Architectures include "i386, ppc, ppc64, ppc7400, ppc970, x86_64" and Build Active Architecture Only is turned off.

Any suggestions as to why this might not launch? There is no error message, the app simply does not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there's no error message? Did you check the console log using /Applications/Utilities/Console.app?

Are you the build settings are correct at the target level (ie, target-level settings don't override project-level settings with incorrect values)?